# Odds of getting a match of ten sided dice

Tags: probability

How would you mathematically determine the odds of rolling two ten sided dice and getting a match (of any number)?

Comment: So, what if I were rolling three dice? would the odds of getting a match become 2/10?

Comment: Also, what would the odds of getting three-of-a-kind be?

Comment: For your first question, what you you mean by *getting a match*? Do you mean rolling three dice and getting *at least two to match*? For your second question, the odds of three of a kind are $P_1(anything)P_2(match the first)P_3(match the first) = (1)(\frac{1}{10})(\frac{1}{10})$ where the subscripts 1,2,3 are the three rolls.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter what the first die rolls, so we only require that the second die match the first. There are 10 possible outcomes of the first die, so we have a one in ten shot:

$$P(match) = \frac{1}{10}$$

Assuming fair, non-interacting dice of course :)

Answer (score 1):

There are 10x10=100 possible outcomes for the dice. There are ten occurrences of matching die, so 10/100.

The odds of this occurring would be 1:9.

Answer (score 0):

There is ten possible results for one roll, with $\frac{1}{10}$ chance of getting each. You have a 100% probability to get one result: $10 * \frac{1}{10} = 1$.

There is also ten possible results for two of the same number in two rolls (1-1, 2-2 etc.), but with $\frac{1}{10}*\frac{1}{10} = \frac{1}{100}$ chance of each. Therefore the chance of rolling any two equal numbers is $10 * \frac{1}{100} = \frac{1}{10}$.

Another way to look at it is to choose a number that exists on the die, and then roll it. What is the chance you'll roll the chosen number? You'll notice that there is no difference if you choose a number yourself, or if you roll a die to choose for you. Therefore, the answer to your original question is the same as to this, i.e. $\frac{1}{10}$.